# Installation of Office 365 on 2008 Macbook with OS -X 10.6 failed

Tags: macbook-pro

I was installing Office 365 on 2008 Macbook with OS X 10.6  and about half way through the installation a pop-up said to close Safari to continue installation. When I did, I received another pop up that installation failed. Was I suppose to X out of Safari which is what I did?

[image: Screenshot of Office install requesting that Safari is closed]

Comment: If I remember correctly the installation won't continue until Safari is completely closed, so the issue isn't that you didn't close Safari properly. I think it must have been something else that caused the installation to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to quit Safari "⌘+Q", "X-ing" out of safari only closes the window, not the program.

Comment: that's the right way to Quit +1

Comment: An alternative is that you can go to Applications -> Utilities -> Activity Monitor and kill any Safari processes that may be running.